# Table Valued Function is returning only one row when the actual result contains multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table `Clients` that contains many columns, however I'm targeting two particular columns `ClientId` and `PIN`. The example that I'm going to provide is not making much sense but I'm just learning more advanced SQL (`T-SQL`) topics and my final goal is something a lot different than what is here.

So I made a function which I would like to return all rows that match certain search criteria. So I have this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_NumberOfClients (@ClientId INT)
  RETURNS @retContactInformation TABLE 
  (
    -- Columns returned by the function
    ClId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    PIN nvarchar(50) NULL
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE 
    @ClId INT, 
    @PIN nvarchar(50) 

    SELECT @ClId = ClientId, @PIN = PIN
    FROM Client
    WHERE PIN LIKE '%7788%'

    IF @ClientId IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @retContactInformation
        SELECT @ClId, @PIN;
    END;
RETURN;
END
```

But when I execute the function:

```
SELECT * FROM
ufn_NumberOfClients(4)
```

I get only one result. Even though it's a valid result, if I execute just

```
SELECT * FROM Client
WHERE PIN LIKE '%7788%'
```

I get 5 results, and the function is returning just the last one.

Two thing which worth mentioning. The example which I use to write the function the `ClId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,` from the table is not `DECLARE`ed after that, but I got error if I don't do it. Also, I pass variable, but I think it's not used so it shouldn't affect the behaviour (or at least I think so).

So how can I return all the results matching the search crieria with a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually insert only one row in the table variable right now, Try this instead :

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_NumberOfClients (@ClientId INT)
RETURNS @retContactInformation TABLE 
(
-- Columns returned by the function
ClId int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
PIN nvarchar(50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @retContactInformation
SELECT ClientId, PIN
FROM Client
WHERE PIN LIKE '%7788%';

RETURN;
END
```